# Adding attribute to dynamically generated elements in *ngfor in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the below html

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-5 tableSectionHeader">Description</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 tableSectionHeader">Quantity</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 tableSectionHeader">Cost</th>
                <th class="col-md-2 tableSectionHeader">Brand</th>
                <th class="col-md-2 tableSectionHeader">Other Brand</th>
                <th class="col-md-1 tableSectionHeader"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngIf="prototypeSampleRequest && prototypeSampleRequest.Items">
            <tr *ngFor="let item of prototypeSampleRequest.Items; let i=index;" 
                prototypeSampleRequest-item [item]="item" [itemIndex]="i" 
                [items]="prototypeSampleRequest.Items" 
                [brands]="brands"
                [isReadOnly]="isReadOnly"
                (itemsCostChangedEvent)="itemsCostChangedEvent()">

            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and here is the C# class

```
[Table("PrototypeSampleRequestItem")]
public class PrototypeSampleRequestItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public PrototypeSampleRequest PrototypeSampleRequest { get; set; }
    public int PrototypeSampleRequestId { get; set; }     
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public int BrandId { get; set; }
}
```

So i am using a service which gets the data for `prototypeSampleRequest.Items` and binds it directly to tr element.

The issue is the textbox that gets generated is of type number and i am getting a pop up saying it's an invalid value for Cost and Quantity field.These fields are of type number when they get generated

Here is the html that gets generated

```
<tr prototypesamplerequest-item="" ng-reflect-item="[object Object]" ng-reflect-item-index="0" ng-reflect-items="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" ng-reflect-is-read-only="false" ng-reflect-brands="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]">

<td>
<input class="form-control input-sm ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="text" ng-reflect-name="item.Name_" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="sa">
</td>

<td>
<input class="form-control input-sm numericField ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="number" ng-reflect-name="item.Quantity_" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="5.66">
</td>

<td>
    <input class="form-control input-sm numericField ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="number" ng-reflect-name="item.Cost_" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="6.5">
</td>

</tr>
```

I was researching the issue and this issue can be fixed by adding step=any to the input field

```
<input type="number" step="any" />
```

So my question is how do I add this attribute to the Cost and Quantity field when they are getting generated by the *ngfor.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem? Where do you want to add them? Why do you think there is something different when you add them in `*ngFor`? How is `<input type="number" step="any"/>` related to the rest of your code above?

Comment: <input class="form-control input-sm numericField ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" type="number" ng-reflect-name="item.Quantity_" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-model="5.66"> this is what gets generated for the Quantity..it's of type number here so while saving the form I get a pop up which tells me if I have entered say 5.5 to choose between 5 or 6 ...the form gets saved though but the pop up always comes up

Comment: I still don't see how the input is related to `*ngFor`. You have `*ngFor` in your first code snippet and `<input>` in the last and no hint how they could be related. Also how is `jquery` involved?

Comment: I edited the question to show the final html that gets generated

Comment: Actually, you need to change dynamically input type?